# Что будет, если не задать параметры куки в php?

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, мне нужно чтоб куки сохранились до закрытии сессии, для этого я подумал, если не задать параметры, то куки сами установится до закрытии сессии, так да, или есть другие варианты?  Это не безопасно?

Comment: Я не понимаю, зачем все время изменяете текст? в чем смысл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у кукисов не задавать время хранения, то они хранятся до закрытия браузера

Comment: Photon, если перед каждым стартом сессии можно просто session_set_cookie_params(), так сработает?

Comment: По логике вещей у любого хостера, да и вообще по умолчанию у php, время жизни сессионных кукисов - до закрытия браузера. Обычных кукисов (если не задано время жизни) - тоже до закрытия браузера

Comment: Photon, точно, работает)